# Save Video file from internet with in application but not in sd card

Tags: android

I want to save video file from internet with in application but not in sd card in Android. I used Eclipse IDE to develop the android application.

How i can achieve this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can store video in application's internal storage, `/data/data/<package_name>/files`..

`getFilesDir()` is return internal storage directory.. You can use it..

Answer (score 0):

the only other way is to save them in internal (phone) storage. saving binary data (especially very large data, like your video) in sqlite db is NOT a good practice.

you can however save the path of the video in your sqlite db, which should make sense.